# I want to print a full square of X with a dash diagonal

Tags: java

I need to print this when I input a number

```
\ X X X X 
X \ X X X
X X \ X X
X X X \ X 
X X X X \
```

but I only managed to reach this point (which i fully understand) to print half a square with a diagonal

```
\
X \
X X \
X X X \ 
X X X X \
```

also any tips and details on basic patterning would be welcome.

I could not find any resources explaining patterning that I understand.

**The code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class sample4 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            int a = in.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                for(int j = 0 ; j <= i ; j++ ) {


                    if (i!=j) {
                System.out.print("X ");

                    }

                    else {  
                        System.out.print("\\");
                    }

                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you give example input and output ? I don't entirely understand your question.  For example, if I input 8, what should output be? What about -4?

Comment: Please be clear with your question. It's not understandable.

Comment: @omar Next time, please take the time to format your post using the tools provided. I added some code formatting which made your question much clearer.

Comment: If I were solving this problem, I would use a for loop to print the first sequence of X's on a line, then print a \, then use another for loop for the next sequence of X's. All of this would be in a for loop to iterate over each line.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Thank you im sorry i did not know how to do it

Comment: the question has been solved thank you everyone !

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's simplify your code by removing the `if` statement. Since you print a `\\` when `i == j`, you can just do it outside of the loop instead:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class sample4 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            int a = in.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                for(int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++ ) {
                    System.out.print("X ");
                }
                System.out.print("\\");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

With this simplification, the next step is to add another for loop to print the rest of the `X`s on a line. You can do this after `System.out.print("\\");`. The details are left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to just change your bound of the inner loop to be `a`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < a; j++ ) {
                if (i!=j) {
                    System.out.print("X ");
                }
                else {  
                    System.out.print("\\ ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the outer loop handles all the rows and the inner handles all the columns. When the two are equal, that means we're at a diagonal and can print the slash. After the slash is printed, the inner loop will continue to the end of the box, rather than just stopping.

Comment: thank you so much it works perfectly what are the things that made my code wrong is it because since i made them equal it would stop after ?

Comment: Your inner loop was only looping until `j <= i`, meaning if `i=1` (i.e. the second row) we would only print 2 columns. What we really want is to print `a` columns always, hence the bound being `j < a`